# Hypothesis testing on two large, non-normal samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I want to compare two large independent groups of integers (each group has 1000+ samples). Both groups are positively skewed. For instance, one group has this distribution:

```py
>>> g1.value_counts()
0     1752
1      258
2      98
3       50
4       45
5       25
8       11
7       10
9        7
6        6
10       3
11       1
dtype: int64
```

So, I have a few ideas in mind and I wanted to know which one is the right choice:

1- Since both groups are pretty large, I can simple compare their means and no hypothesis testing is actually needed.

2- Because the samples are quite large, I can do the T-test.

3- Because the samples are quite skewed, I should do the Mann–Whitney U test.

Which approach is the right one? Or is there a whole different approach that I should be taking? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by telling us what hypothesis you would like to test.  Are you testing the populations to see if they have the same mean?  The same distribution?  Or is it something else?

Comment: What sort of variable is the response itself?

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to give a definitive answer, especially not seeing data from the second group, knowing the source of the data, or knowing your goal in comparing the two groups.

If you don't need a formal hypothesis test and find a clear difference
in the means of the two groups, then (1) might be OK.

(2) With samples as large as yours, a t.test is essentially comparing
two roughly normal observed means, and so may give useful information
even if the count data are not normal. The population variances may be
unequal, so it would be best to use the Welch two-sample t test, 
which does not assume equal variances.

(3) If the two samples have roughly the same shape and possibly different
locations (means or medians), the a Wilcoxon test should be OK in spite
of many ties because of the large sample sizes.

Some explorations, with comments:

If the sample you show is in the vector `x` and a second sample (which I contrived by rounding exponential data to integers) is
in vector `y`, then descriptive statistics can be summarized as follows.

```
table(x); summary(x); sd(x); length(x)
x
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11 
1752  258   78   50   45   25    6   10   11    7    3    1 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.5196  0.0000 11.0000 
[1] 1.360702  # SD
[1] 2246      # sample size

table(y); summary(y); sd(y); length(y)
y
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    8 
1020  942  345  118   53   17    3    2 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  1.0000  0.9268  1.0000  8.0000 
[1] 1.04818
[1] 2500

boxplot(x, y, col="skyblue2", pch=19)
```

[image]

[image]

Results from a Welch 2-sample t test in R are as shown below. I would not
trust the P-value to be exactly accurate, but it is essentially 0, indicating a significant difference in population mean (already strongly hinted at from looking at the sample means).

```
 t.test(x,y)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -11.454, df = 4203.5, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4769072 -0.3375120
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.5195904 0.9268000
```

Because the two-sample Wilcoxon test (same as Mann-Whitney) uses ranks of the combined samples,
ranks will run from 1 through $2246+2500 = 4746,$ it will give a useful idea whether the centers (medians) of the two populations differ, without being
unduly influenced by the extreme skewness of the two samples.

```
wilcox.test(x,y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 1830400, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Others on this site may have additional suggestions. However, depending on the nature of the second sample and
on your goals, all three of your suggestions may be useful.

One additional test that may be useful is Fisher's Exact Test for a 2-by-2 table of 0's and non-0's in the two samples. For the two samples shown here, that test also finds a highly significant difference.

```
TABL = rbind(c(1752, 2246-1752),c(1020, 2500-1020))
TABL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1752  494
[2,] 1020 1480
fisher.test(TABL)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TABL
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
  true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 4.519477 5.860984
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  5.144593
```